# How does the matrix rank affects its Jordan Normal Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let's say I have a matrix whose rank is $\rho(A) =1$.

How does it affect its Jordan Normal Form?

I know that a matrix A is similar to a Jordan Matrix and that means it has the same rank. So if a matrix has a rank of one, doesn't it mean that the Jordan Normal form is:

\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}

A matrix whose rank is 1?

Alan

Answer (score 2):

No, because the matrix you're showing is not a Jordan normal form at all (unless $\lambda=0$). Every off-diagonal $1$ need to appear inside a single Jordan block, that is, connecting two diagonal elements with the *same* value.

The possible Jordan normal forms of rank 1 are

$$\left(\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
  \mathbf{0}_{a\times a} \\ \hline
  & 0 & 1 \\
  & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
  &&& \mathbf{0}_{b\times b} 
 \end{array}\right)$$
and
$$\operatorname{Diag}(0,\ldots,0,\lambda,0,\ldots,0) =
  \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \mathbf{0}_{a\times a} \\ \hline
  & \lambda \\ \hline
  && \mathbf{0}_{b\times b} 
 \end{array}\right) \text{ with }\lambda\ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you. But we can say for sure that A Jordan Normal Form has only one row (and column) with no zero values, right? That is, the definition of the rank?

Comment: @Alan: The rank of a block diagonal matrix is the sum of the ranks of the diagonal blocks, so for a rank-1 JNF matrix there must be exactly one block of rank 1. And the only way for a Jordan block to have rank 1 is if it has one of the two forms above -- which _implies_ that there must be exactly one nonzero element in the matrix, because that happens to be true for both of the possible forms.